# how to use multiple combo boxes to filter data

Tags: vb.net, combobox, filtering

can someone please help me with this problem i'm a beginner in programming.

there is two comboboxes which is S.Y.(school year) and Sem(semester) and i want to use these two combo boxes to have more specific data in the listview below.

```
Private Sub Search_Record()
    Dim conn As New OleDbConnection
    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand
    Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Dim sSQL As String = String.Empty


    Try

        conn = New OleDbConnection(Get_Constring)
        conn.Open()
        cmd.Connection = conn
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        sSQL = "SELECT edp_number, LastName + ', ' + FirstName as name, course as course, Address as address, syear as syear, Sem as sem FROM tblStudent"
        If Me.cboSearchBy.Text = "1st" Then
            sSQL = sSQL & " where Sem like '1st" & Me.txtSearch.Text & "%'"
        Else
            sSQL = sSQL & " where Sem like '2nd" & Me.txtSearch.Text & "%'"
        End If
        cmd.CommandText = sSQL
        da.SelectCommand = cmd
        da.Fill(dt)

        Me.dtgResult.DataSource = dt
        If dt.Rows.Count = 0 Then
            MsgBox("No record found!")
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ErrorToString)
    Finally
        conn.Close()
    End Try
End Sub
```

this code only uses the sem combobox which is cboSearchby so now all i need to know is how to make combobox S.Y to function too and if also to use that texbox to search for firstname and lastname.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just have to add another condition in your If statement:

```
 If Me.cboSearchBy.Text = "1st"  and Me.cboSY.Text = "2014-2015" Then
    sSQL = sSQL & " where Sem like '1st" & Me.txtSearch.Text & "%' and SY like '" & Me.cboSY.Text & "%' "
 Else
    sSQL = sSQL & " where Sem like '2nd" & Me.txtSearch.Text & "%' and SY like '" & Me.cboSY.Text & "%' "
 End If
```

then if you want to add the searching for lastname and firstname, just add another condition on the IF-Statement.

Take Note: In using Logical Operator, **AND** is true if all condition is true while **OR** is true if atleast one of the conditions is true.

Comment: thank you so much sir! i'm grateful, and one more thing sir, there is a conflict between the two for instance when i choose 2014-2016 and also in the 2nd combobox i choose 2nd sem there are still records of 2015-2016 because they're responding to the 2nd sem combo box .. any suggestion to that sir?

Comment: I'm sorry but the question is not clear to me. can you elaborate it? and can you provide examples?

Comment: sorry if my question is not clear, I followed your codes above and there's a problem to it when i chose the "2015-2016" in cboSY and chose the "1st" sem in cboSearchby the results are true for "2015-2016" but it shows the 2nd semester records instead of 1st sem which the intended output.

Comment: try using "=" instead of "like"

Comment: thanks for replying.I tried it but it didn't work, I mean it gives no result  "No record found". I was thinking of using a "switch case" would it be possible in this situation?

Comment: If you select other options in your combobox, is there a result? or there's no record also?

Comment: One Question: What is this txtsearch object? it's a textbox right? what is that for?

Comment: yes, when I select other option in my combobox there will be no result given. if I use the "=" sign, and Yes, textsearch is a textbox, originally before I add the cboSY, the cboSearchby has an item for "Name" and "Edp_number" which when I choose "Name" then I could type the name in the txtSearch to have results.

Comment: `If Me.cboSearchBy.Text = "1st" And Me.cboSY.Text = "2014-2015" Then
                sSQL = sSQL & " where Sem like '1st" & "%' and syear like '" & Me.cboSY.Text & "%' "
            Else
                sSQL = sSQL & " where Sem like '2nd" & "%' and syear like '" & Me.cboSY.Text & "%' "
            End If`

Comment: how do you exactly insert data in the Sem column? is it like "1st Sem" "2nd Sem" or just "1st", "2nd" ... how is it?

Comment: this is the code now, it function except for one thing, when choosing "2015-2016" in cboSY and "1st" in cboSearchby the results are "2015-2016" but for the "2nd" sem even though I chose "1st"

Comment: in the sem column it is just "1st" and "2nd".

Comment: I think you don't need to use the IF statement, just make sure that the data in your database is exactly the same with the data in your Comboboxes, so you can try this:

 
    sSQL = "SELECT edp_number, LastName + ', ' + FirstName as name, course as course, Address as address, syear as syear, Sem as sem FROM tblStudent where Sem = '" &  Me.cboSearchBy.Text & "' and syear = '" & Me.cboSY.Text & "' "

Comment: omg! it works like a charm ! I'm so grateful to you! I've been looking for answers for like 3 days. thank you so much! this is too much to ask but one last thing, when the results are given, I want to be able to type in the txtSearch to have a specific student record.

Comment: so you mean student name? you need to have a specific field for your txtbox. for example create a txtbox and name it as txtLastname then you can add >> AND LastName = '"& txtLastname.txt &"' in you query.